# info frame vs Tcl_Eval

Tags: tcl

I want to know invocation line number of proc. When file is sourced from tclsh
I can put in my proc

```
set infoFrame [info frame -1]
set line [dict get [info frame -1] line]
```

and this will get the line I need. However when I read file from C program and call Tcl_Eval info frame returns "type proc" instead of "type source" and the line number becomes relative to calling proc.

Is there something I can do before Tcl_Eval to specify that I am actually sourcing a file and make info frame behave like file is sourced.

I think Tcl_EvalFile will solve the problem but since the file is already in memory why to read it again. (I have to read content of file in memory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, but no. The internal API you'd need access to in order to make that work is pretty awful, unfortunately, and there are no plans at the moment to expose anything to allow you to improve upon it. Writing to a file is the best approach for now.

Though if you [mount a VFS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tclvfs/), that writing to a file could be no big deal.